# Python: Check whether one element is between two other elements

Tags: python, if-statement

There are two elements: A and B.
I don't know which element is greater. I order to check whether a third element (C) is between them I do the following:

```
if A < C < B or B < C < A:
    print("C is between A and B")
```

Is there a smarter / faster way to do this?

Comment: That's ok for me. You could do `min(A,B)<C<max(A,B)` But I doubt that's smarter/faster though…

Comment: I think you have found the best way

Comment: It's quite fine your way, and more understandable than something like `if sign(C-A)*sign(C-B) < 0` (or without `sign`)

Comment: If you compare lots of different `C`s to a fixed pair of `A` and `B`, it will be worth the time to normalize `A` and `B` so that, say, `A < B` is true, and then you only need to check `A < C < B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the two methods suggested so far, I personally think that `A < C < B or B < C < A` is more readable than `min(A,B) < C < max(A,B)`.

A *very* quick test also suggests that it is also faster on my computer (at least with small `int` values). For example:

```
> python -m timeit("A, B, C = 74, 28, 19; A < C < B or B < C < A")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.267 usec per loop

> python -m timeit("A, B, C = 74, 28, 19; min(A, B) < C < max(A, B)")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.4 usec per loop
```